# UI-Router: why is there a leading "/" on my child state's url?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

I am using AngularJS along with ui-router. My project root is at `/` while my angular app is at `/panel/`.

I have 5 states: `login`, `logout`, `main` (an *abstract* state), `main.home`, and `main.holiday`.

Everything seems fine at first, I could access `main.home`, `login`, `logout`. However, when I access `main.holiday`, **I noticed that there is a leading slash** `/panel//holiday`.

Here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/srph/171b9ee7a0af1a412a5e) to each state (I thought that putting every snippet here would be a bad idea).

My SPA HTML:

```
<!-- ... -->
<head>
<base href="/panel/">
</head>
<!-- ..-->
```

I think this is some sort of bug, no? By the way, here's a link to the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Dz9rk3o2bEzx1AQcRIIa?p=preview) where I seem to have reproduced the problem.

Comment: Maybe try `<base href="/panel">` instead?

Comment: It turns links to ```pane//``` or ```pane/``` for no reason. Let me check.

Comment: Sounds like you tried `<base href="/pane/">` ;D

Comment: I just verified. I am using ```<base href="/panel">``` which happens to be /pane/ when I check the links (*e.g.*, ```domain.com/pane/user/5```, ```domain.com/pane/home```).

Comment: Can you provide a JSFiddle reproducing the problem?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure if I'll be able to.. I'll try, but at the mean time, you can check the project [here](https://github.com/SourceScript/juan-holiday). Angular is at ```/public/app```, and each state is in its respective component at ```/public/app/components```.

Comment: I seem to have reproduced it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Dz9rk3o2bEzx1AQcRIIa?p=preview).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied from my Reddit response (although I seem to not be the first to chime in):

```
// This can have an empty URL unless it needs to add something useful
// For example, it could be '/www' but '/' is pointless and the cause of your issue
var main = {
  name: 'main',
  abstract: true,
  url: '',
  template: '<div ui-view></div>'
};
```

Also:

```
// Add a '/' URL to this state since it's not abstract.
// Else changing from another state to this one won't impact the URL, which is weird
var home = {
  name: 'main.home',
  url: '/',
  template: 'You are in main.home'
};
```

Comment: Although I had already answered this myself, I am voting you up for being more precise. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with both methods:

1. by simple removing the `url` property of the `main` *abstract* state. Or,
2. Setting the `url` property of the `main` *abstract* state to a blank string (`url: ''`).

Comment: You can omit the `url` field of an abstract state. Your issue is still weird though.